# How to show prices that are not yet included?

Tags: shopping-cart, options

In our cart we have optional products (like gift wrapping) that the user can add. We also have options for selected items that might impact the cost (like choosing a hardback book vs a paperback).

How can we make it clear what the price of the optional item is without causing confusion about whether the price is included in the total or not? How can we indicate that selecting an option will change the cost?

- How should we display the price of Gift wrapping when it's not checked by user?
- How should we clarify the price for hardcover and paperback?

[image: mockup of cart with optional gift wrapping price shown in line with purchase but not included in total cost]

Comment: As simple solution could be. Just taking what you have, but not aligning the $5 sign, just place it next to the text. So you have [add gift wrapping for only $5] then when added the item appears in the right aligned column

Answer (score 2):

your design looks good; however you can group it properly by  adding a divider or adding a BG color. User may also like to see some kind of help or info about the 'handcover' or 'paperback', may be you can add a help or info icon.

Flipkart has implemented gift option beautifully..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What ever is designed by you looks good.

1. By default, check the Gift Wrapping, and display its price against it and calculate the total amount and display automatically. As user unchecked it, make the price of it ZERO and do the total amount calculation again automatically. As the user checked / unchecked the Gift Wrapping, he will come to know the price for it.
2. Similarly, as user switches between hardcover and paperback, the price against it can be changed automatically by the system and total amount can be automatically recalculated. As the user switches between hardcover and paperback, he can no the price difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

For 'options' rather than separate products, I'd suggest prefixing the amount with a +. So their cart would look something like:

- Product Name (£10.00)

  - Option: Gift Wraping (+£1.00)

As mentioned already the price for Hardback or Paperback should be reflected immediately as soon as the user makes the selection. You could also do it as an option (assuming hardback costs more)

- Author - Book Title (£15.00)

  - Option: Hardback (+£2.50)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd have 4 columns:

Item Name, Quantity, Cost each, Cost all

So if the checkbox is not checked, this would be:

Gift Wrap, 0, $5, $0

While checked, it would be

Gift Wrap, 1, $5, $5

The user's total cost adds the "Cost all" columns of each line.